# Xamarin Forms Previewer not working in Visual Studio for Mac. Giving error message: The base class associated with this XAML file could not be found

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-previewer

I'm running Visual Studio for Mac and for quite some time all of my xaml files are not showing anything in the previewer and are giving the following message: "The base class associated with this XAML file could not be found. Please double check the class referenced in the 'Class' attribute exists and that the project has been compiled"

Of course I've checked that it does exist and everything compiles successfully. This has been going on for some time in this project in all xaml files even though it runs just fine in the simulator and on devices.

How do you fix this? Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
Since there is no compilation error. Just run the app, check if all the pages you added are working fine and then close app.
Now Rebuild the solution and the design error will be gone.

I don't know why but it worked for me. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I've done this so many times. In fact my app has already gone live. Still have the error in this project. I'm currently using LiveXAML which is 100 times better for designing anyway.

Comment: I just did rebuild solution and the problem went away for me. Build did not fix but rebuild did.

Answer (score 2):

This is the bug exist in Xamrain.Forms Previewer in Visual Studio 15.5 onwards. [This issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/338436/the-base-class-associated-with-this-xaml-could-not.html) has already been filed by me on VS developer community.

There is solution like cleaning, rebuilding and deleting obj & bin folder of android project. Best option is to use VS2019.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I thought that these issues had already been resolved. They have been boasting about the previewer in VS and how it helps with development. Not having this is slowing my development down tremendously. I already deleted my obj & bin folders which didn't work. I'll report the problem myself. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah it's wasting all developer time. Probably you can try creating new project too.

Comment: According to the link provided this issue has been fixed in the most recent version of VS 2019, as of march 2019.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem fairly recently in a new project. Something was crashing in my code when using the designer (worked fine at runtime on device and simulator). As the exception wasn't going away, I deleted the `bin` and `obj` directories throughout the project, and restarted Visual Studio.

Then, the exception went away, but this exact problem occurred: base class associated with the XAML not found.

I rebuilt, restarted, did all that, it just wouldn't go away.

That was until I built the iOS project for the device (not the simulator). The key to this was looking in the log file (`~/Library/Logs/VisualStudio/7.0/iOSDesigner.TIMESTAMP.log`), where there was this line:

```
 [2019-02-19 14:49:52.0] INFO: These assembly will not be uploaded as they cannot be found on disk: 
 [2019-02-19 14:49:52.0] INFO: /Users/***/src/my-app/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/my-app.dll
```

*Debug* is the device build, not the simulator.

**After I rebuilt the device build** ("generic device" was fine), **suddenly the XAML previewer started to work again.**

It would seem that the previewer uses a mix between device and simulator builds, and the text editor itself to update the preview. How.. weird.